# Azure Remote Debugging - Network connection has been lost

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, remote-debugging

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application/API that I am running on Azure.

I am trying to remotely debug my application by attaching a debugger in Visual Studio 2017:

[image]

However, almost immediately this error pops up and debugging is aborted: 
[image]

Sometimes it hits one of my breakpoints but then immediately stops. I have tried restarting my app a number of times but this didn't seem to help.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should have read this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio  But I my test Lab, it works fine.  Did the browser has been opened  ?

Comment: Perhaps you could check the configuration about debugging in Tools in Visual Studio and app settings in Azure. Such as Microsoft Symbol Server in debugging options.(https://cushen.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/fixing-the-network-connection-to-my-computer-has-been-lost-debugging-will-be-aborted/).

Comment: And if my debugging has been running, I forgot to close it, I also get the same error like you.  This seems to just be timed out. The result like this: link:https://image.ibb.co/cagzNn/debugerror1.png

Comment: Will try it tonight! Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: This happens to me frequently and also breaks my app service. Even restarting it doesn't fix it...it appears to wokr like an hour later.